# Difficulty in using SDL_LoadBMP with relative path in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, relative-path, portability, sdl-2

Firstly, I know this question has been asked many, many times; I have read at least five or ten variations, but none of the answers given worked in my case. I have the line:

`helloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("helloworld.bmp");`

in the `main.cpp` file of my Xcode 5 project. The directory structure is as follows:

```
TestProject1
    main.cpp
    Resources
        helloworld.bmp
    TestProject1.1
TestProject1.xcodeproj
```

Of course, I have tried different paths, i.e. `Resources/helloworld.bmp`, and yes, the Resources folder is imported into the project. However, the statement returns `NULL` because (according to SDL_Error) it cannot find the file. Now, the line:

`helloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("/fully/qualified/path/to/helloworld.bmp");`

works fine, so it is not a problem with my code. What is the generally accepted way to get Xcode to work with relative paths for resources? I am looking for a method that will be portable (to the platforms that SDL supports, ofc on different computers/devices) when I make a larger project, and am open to using a different IDE if Xcode cannot make portable C++ projects. Miscellaneous other things I have tried after reading other questions:

Adding `helloworld.bmp` to Build Phases > Copy Files.

Adding the code:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This makes relative paths work in C++ in Xcode by changing directory to the Resources folder inside the .app bundle
#ifdef __APPLE__
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(mainBundle);
char path[PATH_MAX];
if (!CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(resourcesURL, TRUE, (UInt8 *)path, PATH_MAX))
{
    // error!
}
CFRelease(resourcesURL);

chdir(path);
std::cout << "Current Path: " << path << std::endl;
#endif
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

to the beginning of `main.cpp` (returns "Expected unqualified-id" compiler error on the `if (!CFURL...)` line).

Using an absolute path - as I said, this works, but I want portability.

Calling `getcwd`: this is C++ code. Is there something I am missing here? It doesn't seem like `getcwd` is a C++ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Build Phases` you need to create a new build phase of type `Copy Files`.

Set `Destination` to be 'Resources' and leave Subpath blank unless you want to have a subfolder in your resources (can be useful when you have a lot and want to separate eg fonts, textures, sounds etc)

Leave `Copy only when installing` **unticked**

Then just add the resources to that build phase, in your case helloworld.bmp

You should then be able to load by doing:

```
helloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("helloworld.bmp");
```

or if you used a Subpath:

```
helloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("textures/helloworld.bmp");
```

This is the same sort of way you could bundle the SDL2.framework with your application. There is a tutorial here - http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/ and in Part 3 it describes how to bundle the frameworks if you are interested.

Overal though the best way to do fully portable builds is going to be something like CMake or Gradle.